# Why does minimum height of a trapezium node affect also the width?

Tags: tikz-pgf, width, height, shapes

If I change `minimum height=...` of a `trapezium` node, also the width changes.

It doesn't happen with standard rectangle nodes.

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric, shapes.misc, matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    basenode/.style={
        draw=lightgray, align=center,
        text=black, very thick, 
        text height=1.75ex, text depth=.25ex,
        text width=7em, 
    },
    inout/.style={
        basenode,
        minimum height=5ex,
        trapezium,
        trapezium left angle=60, 
        trapezium right angle=120,
    },
    inout2/.style={
        basenode,
        minimum height=7ex,
        trapezium,
        trapezium left angle=60, 
        trapezium right angle=120,
    },
    instruction/.style={
        basenode,  
        minimum height=5ex,
        rounded corners,
    },
    instruction2/.style={
        basenode,  
        minimum height=7ex,
        rounded corners,    
    },
]
\matrix[
    matrix of nodes, row sep=7ex, column sep=7em,
    anchor=base
    ]{
    |[inout]|\texttt{trapezium} & with \texttt{minimum height=5ex}\\
    |[inout2]|\texttt{trapezium} & with \texttt{minimum height=7ex}\\
    |[instruction]|\texttt{rectangle} & with \texttt{minimum height=5ex}\\
    |[instruction2]|\texttt{rectangle} & with \texttt{minimum height=7ex}\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: see, what happen if you to trapezium parameters add `trapezium stretches`. (see manual, page 697).

Comment: @Zarko Works perfectly, thank you! If you would like to add an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is known issues. in tikz & pgf manual you can find on page 697 the folowing:

> /pgf/trapezium stretches=boolean  (default true)
>
> This key controls
> whether pgf allows the width and the height of the trapezium to be
> enlarged independently, when considering any minimum size
> specification. This is initially false, ensuring that the shape “looks
> the same but bigger” when enlarged.
>
> By setting hbooleani to true, the trapezium can be stretched horizontally or vertically.

an example from there:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
my node/.style={trapezium, fill=#1!20, draw=#1!75, text=black},
trapezium stretches=true % <---
                    ]
\draw [help lines] grid (3,2);
\node [my node=red] {A};
\node [my node=green, minimum height=1.5cm] at (1, 1.25) {B};
\node [my node=blue, minimum width=1.5cm] at (2, 0) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]